# multiple angular filter for text but also greater than / less than

Tags: angularjs, filter

```
tr.row(ng-repeat="i in items | filter:search" 

input(type="text" ng-model="search.desc")
input(type="text" ng-model="search.comment")
```

This works marvelously, I can filter items by desc and comment.

Now, I also need to filter by

- amount
- date

Both will have an input for greater than and less than (resp. after / before).
For example for amount:

```
input(type="text" ng-model="search.amount") //this one would be the minimum value input
input(type="text" ng-model="search.amount") //this one would be the maximum value input
```

How can I combine this with the already working desc and comment filters which I would rather want to keep? I guess I will have to write some custom function - but could I combine this harnessing the existing text filtering?

Note on syntax: using jade template engine on nodejs

Answer (score 5):

I think you have to write some code to check whether the amount satisfies. Since filters can be chained, its harmless I think.

first you name min & max amount

```
input(type="text" ng-model="search.minAmount") //this one would be the minimum value input
input(type="text" ng-model="search.maxAmount") //this one would be the maximum value input
```

in your controller, define a function

```
$scope.matchAmount = function(item){
     reuturn item.amount >= $scope.search.minAmount && item.amount <= $scope.search.maxAmount
}
```

finally,use it in you template

```
ng-repeat="i in items | filter:search | filter: matchAmount
```

Comment: the upvote for both you guys in the first place is because you made me understand that I can chain filters.

Answer (score 2):

You can write [custom-filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09) say `amountRange` and `dateRange`.

For `amountRange` filter the input looks like

```
input(type="text" ng-model="amount.minAmount") //instead of search.minAmount
input(type="text" ng-model="amount.maxAmount") //instead of search.maxAmount
```

You can apply `amountRange` after your `search` filter in `HTML`

```
tr.row(ng-repeat="i in items | filter:search | amountRange:amount"
```

The `amountRange` filter

```
  myApp.filter('amountRange', function() {
    return function(input, amount) {
      var filteredAmount = [];
      angular.forEach(input, function(item) {
        if (amount && (item.amount >= amount.minAmount && item.amount <= amount.maxAmount))
          filteredAmount.push(item);
      });
      return filteredAmount.length > 0 ? filteredAmount : input
    };
  });
```

Here is a working <kbd>[**Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/DAX5nc0axaVSTBpSlRjJ?p=preview)</kbd> for `amountRange` filter, you can do similar for `dateRange` filter.

Comment: the upvote for both you guys in the first place is because you made me understand that I can chain filters.

Answer (score 0):

I like both answers, but both have some issues.
So I don't really know which one to accept, but upvoted both.

Actually here's what I did, not sure I want to accept mine either, because it looks as there may be a more efficient way to do it.

In fact, I also want that if someone enters an amount in minAmount only, it would filter from minAmount upwards, and if maxAmount only, from maxAmount downwards.

Here's what I came up with:

```
  $scope.matchAmount = function(item) {
    if ($scope.minAmount && (!$scope.maxAmount)) {
      return item.amount >= $scope.minAmount; 
    } else if ((!$scope.minAmount) && $scope.maxAmount) {
       return item.amount <= $scope.maxAmount;
    } else if ($scope.minAmount && $scope.maxAmount) {
      return item.amount >= $scope.minAmount && item.amount <= $scope.maxAmount;
    } else {
      return item.amount;
    }
  }
```

Also, in the view

```
input.filter(type="text" ng-model="minAmount" placeholder="Minimum amount")
```

@sunderls, take note that your `ng-model='search.minAmount'` didn't work, the `'search.'` prefix needed to be removed in order to work in my case.

Comment: I think you ought to mark @sunderls as having the answer.  Your answer is just a variation of his concept.  It's the same concept I use as well.  Most likely the reason you had to remove the 'search.' prefix was because you didn't initialize it in your controller first (e.g. $scope.search = {}).  This allows you to define multiple search fields in your view all as properties of the search object.  The code is easier to follow this way.